# I'm new to Syntax directed translation and I didn't understand the precedence in this

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

```
E-E*T
 /T
T-T+F
 /F
F-num
```

Evaluate 2*3+5*6+4

In the above productions how come + sign has higher precedence than  * sign. In general * has always higher precedence than *. Then why not in this question

Comment: Could you check your production rules? There is no `+` anywhere.

Comment: Now check @makadev

Comment: Those don't look like production rules using any variation of (E)BNF syntax that I've seen.  Try to reformulate them using more standard notations; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form.  Then maybe we can understand your problem.  (Maybe you mean;  "E=E*T | T"?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty with grammars so please correct me if I'm wrong.

The fast answer is: This is a typical unambiguous context free grammar for arithmetic expressions just with `+` and `*` switched.

Have a look at the syntax tree by systematically applying the productions if we assume that `E` is the root/start. This makes it a bit more clear what is going on.

```
2 * 3 + 5 * 6 + 4
F   F   |   F   |
|   |   |   |   |
|   T + F   T + F
T     |       |
|     |       |
E *   T       |
  |           |
  E       *   T
          |
          E
```

`+` has higher precedence and binds it's surrounding `T` and `F` first while `*` will get the leftover `T` and `E`. The rule dependencies are what create the *precedence*. You could easily modify it [to change precedence or introduce new levels](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs536.s08/course.hold/html/NOTES/3.CFG.html#exp)

```
E-E+G
 /G
G-G.J
 /J
J-J*F
 /F
F-num
```

To make `*` highest, `+` lowest with a new symbol `.` which gets higher precedence as `+` and lower than `*`. In depth information can be found at a lot Computer Science/Compiler Construction departments like [here](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeProgLang/Grammar/Arith-Exp/), [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs536.s08/course.hold/html/NOTES/3.CFG.html) and [here](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/173/notes/05_grammars).